# How to display changes in firestore in Angular app?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Angular app and use Firestore database. I am quite new in Angular, so please be explicit with your answers. Parts of my code are displayed below.
I use Firestore onSnapshot, which listens for changes in database. I am trying to save actual events from database into events variable. But when I first visit the page, where should be displayed the events, there is nothing. If I visit the page for the second time, it is there as intended.
I think, that the getEvents function returns empty object first, but after that events variable in the service is updated. Is there a way to get actual value of the service variable events and display it in my component template?

I have a service:

```
export class EventsService {
  events: Record<string, Event> = {} as Record<string, Event>

  constructor() { }

  async getEvents() {
    getEventsSnapshot = onSnapshot(eventsCollectionQuery, (querySnapshot) => {
      this.events = {};
      querySnapshot.forEach((d) => {
        const eventId = d.id;
        const eventData: Event = {
          id: eventId,
          name: d.data()['name'],
          location: d.data()['location'],
          geolocationArea: d.data()['geolocationArea'],
          date: new Date(d.data()['date']),
          description: d.data()['description'],
          image: d.data()['image'],
        };
        this.events[eventId] = eventData;
      });
    });
    return this.events;
  }
}
```

EventsComponent:

```
<div class="p-2" *ngIf="(events | keyvalue)?.length">
  <app-event
    *ngFor="let event of events | keyvalue"
    [event]="event.value">
  </app-event>
</div>


export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {
  events: Record<string, Event> = {} as Record<string, Event>;

  constructor(private eventsService: EventsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEvents();
  }

  async getEvents() {
    this.events = await this.eventsService.getEvents()
  }
}
```

EventComponent that uses data from parent EventsComponent:

```
<div class=" my-card card mb-2 border-0 shadow">
  <div class="d-flex g-0 flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <img [src]="event.image" class="rounded-start" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="title-container col p-2 ps-3 pe-0">
      <p class="card-text fw-bold">{{ event.name }}</p>
      <p class="card-text">{{ event.location }}</p>
      <p class="card-text">{{ event.date.toISOString().split('T')[0] }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="description-container col py-2 px-3 d-none d-sm-block">
      <div class="description-subcontainer text-secondary">
        {{ event.description }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to getEvents()?
this.events = await this.eventsService.getEvents().subscribe()

I haven' tried your code so just a question...